# Spring Security HTTP FormLogin

Tags: spring, security, http, spring-boot

I have a problem with my Spring Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/",
                            "/index/**",
                            "/register",
                            "/doregister",
                            "/login",
                            "/dologin",
                            "/logout-success",
                            "/confirmregister",
                            "/invaliduser",
                            "/expiredtoken",
                            "/userstatuslog",
                            "/verifyemail")
                    .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                            .authenticated()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/login",
                            "logout")
                    .permitAll()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/static/css/**",
                            "/css/custom.css",
                            "/js/**",
                            "/images/**"
                            )
                        .permitAll()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/forbidden",
                            "/edit-profile-about",
                            "/doeditprofileabout",                      
                            "/profile"
                            )
                    .hasRole("USER")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/controlpanel",
                            "/forbidden",
                            "/edit-profile-about",
                            "/doeditprofileabout",                      
                            "/profile"
                            )
                    .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                            .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .deleteCookies("remove")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                            .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success")
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));

        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(usuarioService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
```

Everytime, I do login it sends me to the bootstrap file...

> localhost:8080/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

or...

> localhost:8080/css/custom.css

or...

> localhost:8080/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

but not to the same one (it seems random! :-)

Then sometimes the *CSS* works and sometimes not. In the login form it has no styles, but only sometimes, because when I run the app, it has the styles. And when I do login too, but not when I logout or try to login again. So when the user is correctly logged in, it has styles again.

And when I tried to access "/controlpanel" with a user (with ROLE_USER) it allows access (and it should not), but when I do it with a user (Role_ADMIN) it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when your static resources are filtered by Spring Security.

Try to ignore these resources at all:

```
@Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/path/**");
        }
```

define patterns to meet all your locations.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. I include in those paths the static, css, js, images, but it does not work. Do you know of any documentation that i can take a look at? Thanks again.

Comment: What does it mean that it don't work? When you look what resources are read while page is loaded (in in Webdeveloper tools, tab Network), do you see `HTTP 401` for your static content files? Or anything else? Add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your css files is not accessible by guest. So after logging in, you will be redirected back to it. Sometime css in login page works because of browser caching.

Try to change your configuration to

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
                "/",
                "/index/**",
                "/register",
                ...).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(
                "/login",
                "logout").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(            // You need to add all css file here
                "/static/css/**",
                "/css/custom.css",
                "/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.cs‌​‌​‌​s",
                "/js/**",
                "/images/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(
                "/forbidden",
                "/edit-profile-about",
                "/doeditprofileabout",                      
                "/profile").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers(
                "/controlpanel",
                "/forbidden",
                "/edit-profile-about",
                "/doeditprofileabout",                      
                "/profile").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
        ...
```

Comment: Hi, it stills shows the localhost:8080/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css after login... Thanks

Comment: Do you know of any documentation that i can take a look at? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, it stills shows the localhost:8080/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.cs‌​s after login... It didnt show any error before. Thanks

Comment: I think it is because of this css file (localhost:8080/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.cs‌s) is not permit to access by guest so after login it will redirect you back to this css file. Try to do something like `antMatchers("css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.cs‌​‌​s").permitAll()` or ignore it like @user1315357 suggests.